# Changing a cell's color while in "highlighted" state

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

How can I change the default (blue) color that appears on a table view's cell when it is tapped?
(Just the overlay color, as when You tap on an option in Settings.app and it gets blue before taking You there)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use any of them

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
//or
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray];
```

Maybe this will help you

Answer (score 4):

> selectedBackgroundView
>
> The view used as the background of the cell when it is selected.

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *selectedBackgroundView
```

from [UITableViewCell Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Make an `UIView`, set whatever `backgroundColor` you wish and set it as a `selectedBackgroundView` for your cell.